# How can I retrieve a table from stored procedure to a datatable?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I created a stored procedure so as to return me a table.

Something like this:

```
create procedure sp_returnTable
body of procedure
select * from table
end
```

When I call this stored procedure on the frontend what code do I need to write to retrieve it in a datatable object?

I wrote code something like the following. I basically want to know retrieving and storing table into an object of datatable. All my queries are running, but I don't know how to retrieve table into a datatable through a stored procedure

```
DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
cmd.Connection = _CONN;

cmd.CommandText = SPNameOrQuery;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
OpenConnection();
adp.Fill(dtTable);
CloseConnection();
```

Here in this code a command has been bound with the stored procedure name and its parameters. Will it be returning me a datatable from the stored procedure?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
string connString = "<your connection string>";
string sql = "name of your sp";

using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString)) 
{
    try 
    {
        using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter()) 
        {
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();   
            da.Fill(ds, "result_name");

            DataTable dt = ds.Tables["result_name"];

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
                //manipulate your data
            }
        }    
    } 
    catch(SQLException ex) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SQL Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Modified from [Java Schools Example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/ModifyDataTableinsertdatatodatabasetable.htm)

Comment: I didn't understood, how the stored procedure is getting executed as I dont uses dataset or use rarely. "cmd.ExecuteQuery()" can u xplain me whether i can use this to do the same thing

Comment: When you call "Fill" it will run the command you have associated with the "Select" statement and put the results into a table called "result_name". This is the same behaviour as calling ExecuteReader(), having the rows read singularly and placed into a List<List<Columns>> type structure.

Comment: Is it not better to close the connection soon after recieving the data in the dataset?

Comment: You dont need to open or close the connection wheh you use DataAdapter.Fill. Also, i would use use the using-statement instead. Its more readable. You should also dispose the SqlCommand and the SqlDataAdapter.

Comment: @FabianSilva   What about having output param from t sql beside datatable? how to get output param too? Is it possible? Sample?

Comment: @AhmadEbrahimi I'm not are who answered question (edited it), but check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905782/using-stored-procedure-output-parameters-in-c-sharp http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-return-Output-parameter-from-Stored-Procedure-in-ASPNet-in-C-and-VBNet.aspx this have a example to use output params, hope that this help you

Comment: @GrayWizardx What about having output param from t sql beside datatable? how to get output param too? Is it possible? Sample?

Answer (score 6):

Set the `CommandText` as well, and call `Fill` on the `SqlAdapter` to retrieve the results in a `DataSet`:

```
var con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "connection string";
var com = new SqlCommand();
com.Connection = con;
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
com.CommandText = "sp_returnTable";
var adapt = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapt.SelectCommand = com;
var dataset = new DataSet();
adapt.Fill(dataset);
```

(Example is using parameterless constructors for clarity; can be shortened by using other constructors.)

Comment: do i need to tell adapter for select command adapt.SelectCommand = com; ?

Comment: @Shantanu Gupta: Yeah, or you can use `SqlDataAdapter(com)` to pass `SelectCommand` as a parameter to the constructor

Answer (score 2):

Explaining if any one want to send some parameters while calling stored procedure as below,

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
            {
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(storedProcName, con))
                {
                    foreach (var item in sqlParams)
                    {
                        item.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                        item.DbType = DbType.String;
                        command.Parameters.Add(item);
                    }
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                    {
                        adapter.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }
            }
```