# Using stored procedure output parameters in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am having a problem returning an output parameter from a Sql Server stored procedure into a C# variable. I have read the other posts concerning this, not only here but on other sites, and I cannot get it to work. Here is what I currently have. Currently I am just trying to print the value that comes back. The following code returns a null value. What I an trying to return is the primary key. I have tried using `@@IDENTITY` and `SCOPE_INDENTITY()` (i.e. `SET @NewId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()`).

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InsertContract
    @ContractNumber varchar(7),

    @NewId int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT into [dbo].[Contracts] (ContractNumber)
        VALUES (@ContractNumber)

    Select @NewId = Id From [dbo].[Contracts] where ContractNumber = @ContractNumber
END
```

Opening the database:

```
pvConnectionString = "Server = Desktop-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Database = PVDatabase; User ID = sa;
    PASSWORD = *******; Trusted_Connection = True;";

try
{
    pvConnection = new SqlConnection(pvConnectionString);
    pvConnection.Open();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    databaseError = true;
}
```

Executing the command:

```
pvCommand = new SqlCommand("usp_InsertContract", pvConnection);

pvCommand.Transaction = pvTransaction;
pvCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;    

pvCommand.Parameters.Clear();
pvCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ContractNumber", contractNumber));

SqlParameter pvNewId = new SqlParameter();
pvNewId.ParameterName = "@NewId";
pvNewId.DbType = DbType.Int32;
pvNewId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
pvCommand.Parameters.Add(pvNewId);

try
{
    sqlRows = pvCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (sqlRows > 0)
        Debug.Print("New Id Inserted =  ", 
            pvCommand.Parameters["@NewId"].Value.ToString()); 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Print("Insert Exception Type: {0}", e.GetType());
        Debug.Print("  Message: {0}", e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd also use SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead of requerying the same table., and in case you get a 'query can return multiple results' error, when assigning to a single output var.

Comment: Do I use the set command to do this? SET NewId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()? I replaced the select statement with the following...SET @NewId = SCOPE_IDENTITY() and I still receive a null value back.

Comment: Yes I can see the row in the database.

Comment: I have added the opening of the connection and the creating of the command to the code.

Comment: Could you try to commit the transaction before reading the output parameter?

Comment: Thats definitely worth a thought Steve!

Comment: I have tried that and it still returned a null value.

Comment: I have tried to setup a database and tested your code on LinqPAD, the only difference is in the SP where I have removed the prefix [dbo] and the square brakets around [Contract]. Everything works as expected. The last thing to check are the field data type and the Identity flag on your table, are they correct (ID=Int+Identity)?

Comment: This is the definition when I create the table....[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL

Comment: Also, when you talk about a NULL value, do you mean a DBNull.Value that when converted via ToString() is an empty string? or you get an exception?

Comment: A DBNull value that when converted it becomes an empty string.

Comment: When I look at the column in sql server it says the following... Id(PK, int, Not Null)

Comment: Curious that the `Id` column doesn't say `IDENTITY`.  As an aside, there have been problems in several versions of SQL Server with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.  Using an `OUTPUT` clause on the `INSERT` will always get you the correct answer, but it does involve adding another table.  See the _Workarounds_ tab [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328811/scope-identity-sometimes-returns-incorrect-value#details).

Comment: Just to divide the problem in half, you could add `set @NewId = 42` at the end of your stored procedure and determine whether or not the value makes it back to C#.

Comment: The column does say that it is an identity column.

Comment: Now that it is 2019, 7 years after the question, readers should check out the OUTPUT clause in modern Sql Server INPUT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements.  Even so, getting the value from an output parameter is still valid, even if the output statement by default will just return as a result set, so you wouldn't use an output parameter or return value in the simple case.

Answer (score 148):

I slightly modified your stored procedure (to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY`) and it looks like this:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InsertContract
    @ContractNumber varchar(7),
    @NewId int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Contracts] (ContractNumber)
    VALUES (@ContractNumber)

    SELECT @NewId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

I tried this and it works just fine (with that modified stored procedure):

```cs
// define connection and command, in using blocks to ensure disposal
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(pvConnectionString ))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_InsertContract", conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        
    // set up the parameters
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContractNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 7);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@NewId", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    // set parameter values
    cmd.Parameters["@ContractNumber"].Value = contractNumber;

    // open connection and execute stored procedure
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // read output value from @NewId
    int contractID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@NewId"].Value);
    conn.Close();
}
```

Does this work in your environment, too? I can't say why your original code won't work - but when I do this here, VS2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2, it just works flawlessly....

If you don't get back a value - then I suspect your table `Contracts` might not really have a column with the `IDENTITY` property on it.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your time in answering this for those of us Googling it years later. :-)

Comment: @marc_s if the size of Varchar output is unknown then how to tackle that problem.

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add("@NewId", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; needs to be altered to cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewId", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;  This is because it has depreciated

Answer (score 3):

Before changing stored procedure please check what is the output of your current one. In SQL Server Management run following:

```sql
DECLARE @NewId int
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[usp_InsertContract]
            N'Gary',
            @NewId OUTPUT
SELECT  @NewId
```

See what it returns. This may give you some hints of why your out param is not filled.

Comment: This just about works as an answer, but probably should be a comment, however I can't convert it because of the multiple @ character usage (even mods are denied that right) and I can't be bothered editing it to make it work. :)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and first closed the connection and then read the parameters and it worked fine.
you can use `pvConnection.Close();`  before read the output parameter
try
{
pvConnection = new SqlConnection(pvConnectionString);
pvConnection.Open();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
databaseError = true;
}

```
pvCommand = new SqlCommand("usp_InsertContract", pvConnection);

pvCommand.Transaction = pvTransaction;
pvCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;    

pvCommand.Parameters.Clear();
pvCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ContractNumber", contractNumber));

SqlParameter pvNewId = new SqlParameter();
pvNewId.ParameterName = "@NewId";
pvNewId.DbType = DbType.Int32;
pvNewId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
pvCommand.Parameters.Add(pvNewId);

try
{
    sqlRows = pvCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    pvConnection.Close();
    if (sqlRows > 0)
        Debug.Print("New Id Inserted =  ", 
            pvCommand.Parameters["@NewId"].Value.ToString()); 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Print("Insert Exception Type: {0}", e.GetType());
        Debug.Print("  Message: {0}", e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mostafa, could you share with us this code?

Comment: excuse me, I did not understand you!

Comment: No problem :-) I see you edited the answer in July with the code. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, excuse me. Now I see this.

Answer (score 1):

Stored Procedure.........

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InsertContract
    @ContractNumber varchar(7)
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT into [dbo].[Contracts] (ContractNumber)
        VALUES (@ContractNumber)

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [SCOPE_IDENTITY]
END
```

C#

```
pvCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

pvCommand.Parameters.Clear();
pvCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ContractNumber", contractNumber));
object uniqueId;
int id;
    try
    {
    uniqueId = pvCommand.ExecuteScalar();
     id = Convert.ToInt32(uniqueId);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Print("  Message: {0}", e.Message);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** "I still get back a DBNull value....Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types. I'll take this up again tomorrow. I'm off to my other job,"

**I believe the Id column in your SQL Table isn't a identity column.**

[image]

Comment: But this answers not the question why the output parameter for the new id returns null. With `ExecuteScalar` you can retrieve a return value not an output parameter.

Comment: I also receive the following error when I make this change...Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Thats because the Parameter is called SCOPE_IDENTITY, in SQL; C# is still looking for a parameter called @ContractNumber.

Comment: ContractNumber is the value being added to the table. The primary key is called Id.

Comment: ExecuteScalar returns an object, not an int. I receive an exception when I execute the code.

Comment: Hi Gary, I thought you'd be able to work that bit out, but I edit my answer none-the-less.

Comment: I still get back a DBNull value....Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types. I'm off to my other job,. I'll take this up again tomorrow. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: The column does says it is an identity column

Comment: something else must be wrong because this works perfectly for me.

Comment: Sorry to delete my answer, the down vote really got to me. I know its bad form on my part and it can get you banned from answering questions. To the down voter its not cool and I would like to know why?

Answer (score 0):

In your C# code, you are using transaction for the command.
Just commit the transaction and after that access your parameter value, you will get the value.
Worked for me. :)