# SQL Server stored procedure that returns a boolean if table exists, c# implementation

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure that takes a single argument, the name of a table, and returns 1 if it exists in the database, 0 if it does not. In SQL Server Management Studio testing my stored procedure works exactly as I'd like it to, however I'm having trouble getting that value for use in my C# program.

My options seem to be `ExecuteScalar()`, `ExecuteNonQuery()` or `ExecuteReader()`, none of which seem appropriate for the task, nor can I get them to even retrieve my stored procedure's result.

I have tried assigning my parameter with both `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` and `cmd.Parameters.Add` again to no avail.

Comment: Is your stored procedure returning or selecting the result?  It is easier if you "select TableExists=1" instead of "return 1".  Then you can use ExecuteScalar().

Comment: Yes it is returning. I will look into using a SELECT instead if it makes things easier.

Comment: I prefer an output parameter.  But its a personal preference.  See the answer to this one.  But "yes" to the "use the SELECT"        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905782/using-stored-procedure-output-parameters-in-c-sharp

Comment: marc_s answer that is.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming you have a stored procedure like this which selects either a 0 (table does not exist) or 1 (table does exist)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DoesTableExist (@TableName NVARCHAR(100))
AS 
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE Name = @TableName)
        SELECT 1
    ELSE
        SELECT 0  
END
```

then you can write this C# code to get the value - use `.ExecuteScalar()` since you're expecting only a single row, single column:

```
// set up connection and command
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("your-connection-string-here"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.DoesTableExist", conn))
{
    // define command to be stored procedure
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // add parameter
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TableName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = "your-table-name-here";

    // open connection, execute command, close connection
    conn.Open();
    int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Now `result` will contain either a `0` if the table doesn't exist - or `1`, if it does exist.

Comment: Yes and you need to cast result as bit if you are returning boolean value in c#

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
 var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnVal", SqlDbType.Int);
 returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

Your stored procedure should return 0 or 1.