# the equivalent of a sql procedure in access query

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures

i have a sql procedure, but as access accepts only single statement, i'd like to control the differents statement through the code side using C# with Dbcommand...in order to find the equivalent. here is the sql procedure, i'm gonna show you the C# code but i got an error.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateOrders
(@cartId char(36)) 
As
/*insert a new record into Commande étape 1 :"PasserCommande1"*/
DECLARE @CmdID int
INSERT INTO Commande DEFAULT VALUES
/*save the new commande id*/
SET @CmdID = @@IDENTITY
/*Add the order detail to DetailsCommande(orderdetails table) étape 2 :"PasserCommande2"*/
INSERT INTO DetailsCommande ( CmdID, ProduitID, ProduitTitre, Quantite, CoutUnitaire )
SELECT [@CmdID], livres.NumLivre, livres.titre, ShoppingCart.Quantite, livres.prix
FROM livres INNER JOIN ShoppingCart ON livres.NumLivre = ShoppingCart.ProduitID
WHERE ShoppingCart.CartID=[@CartID]
/*Clear the shopping Cart étape 3 :"PasserCommande3"*/
DELETE FROM ShoppingCart
WHERE CartID = @CartID
/*return the order id étape 4:"PasserCommande4"*/
SELECT @CmdID;
```

so i separated the procedure in 4 differents statements, so that i can call them one by one with c#, but i got a error when retreiving the @@identity value from the Commande table to put it in the DetailsCommande. the CmdID has an identity property in the table Commande. here is what i'm trying to do in C#:

```
public static string PasserCommande()
{
    //étape 1

    //on obtient l'objet configuré DbCommande
    DbCommand m_cmd = LibAccesGenerique.CreerCmd();
    //on définit la procédure stockée
    m_cmd.CommandText = "PasserCommande_1";
    LibAccesGenerique.ExecuteNonQuery(m_cmd);
    //étape 2
    DbCommand m_cmd1 = LibAccesGenerique.CreerCmd();
    m_cmd1.CommandText = "PasserCommande_2";
    //on crée un nouveau paramètre
    DbParameter m_param = m_cmd1.CreateParameter();
    m_param.ParameterName = "@CmdID";
    m_param.Value = "@@IDENTITY";
    m_param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
    m_cmd1.Parameters.Add(m_param);
    //2ème param
    m_param = m_cmd1.CreateParameter();
    m_param.ParameterName = "@CartID";
    m_param.Value = ShoppingCartId;
    m_param.DbType = DbType.String;
    m_param.Size = 36;
    m_cmd1.Parameters.Add(m_param);
    LibAccesGenerique.ExecuteNonQuery(m_cmd1);
    //étape3
    DbCommand m_cmd2 = LibAccesGenerique.CreerCmd();
    m_cmd2.CommandText = "PasserCommande3";
    DbParameter m_param2 = m_cmd2.CreateParameter();
    m_param2 = m_cmd1.CreateParameter();
    m_param2.ParameterName = "@CartID";
    m_param2.Value = ShoppingCartId;
    m_param2.DbType = DbType.String;
    m_param2.Size = 36;
    m_cmd2.Parameters.Add(m_param);
    LibAccesGenerique.ExecuteNonQuery(m_cmd2);
    //étape 4
    DbCommand m_cmd3 = LibAccesGenerique.CreerCmd();
    m_cmd3.CommandText = "PasserCommande_4";
   //on créer un nouveau paramètre
    DbParameter m_param1 = m_cmd3.CreateParameter();
    m_param1.ParameterName = "@CmdID";
    m_param1.Value = "@@IDENTITY";
    //m_param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
    m_param1.DbType = DbType.Int32;
    m_cmd3.Parameters.Add(m_param1);
    return LibAccesGenerique.ExecuteScalar(m_cmd3);

}
```

the error comes at etape 2 as i put in my comments. the exception says that the format of the input string is incorrect... i'm sure it comes when i try to assign the @@identity to @cmdID paramater. i don't know if there is a another way to code it.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

`@@IDENTITY` works with access, but it's a bit ordinary. Try sending it as a straight command

```sql
SELECT @@IDENTITY;
```

assigning the results to a variable using `ExecuteScalar`, then assigning that variable to the parameter instead. Also bear in mind that with access, `@@IDENTITY` only works with a normal `AutoNumber`, not a `ReplicationID` (GUID).

Answer (score 0):

You should return `@@Identity` as an 'Output' parameter. Add an output parameter to your stored procedure and add a the same parameter to your C# code with `Direction = ParameterDirection.Output`.

See this answer for a great example: [Using stored procedure output parameters in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10908586/772086)

Also, as a best practice, consider changing `@@Identity` to `Scope_Identity()`.