# Return bigint from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have written a stored procedure in SQL Server which will return a `Bigint` value

```
alter procedure [dbo].adding 
    @one bigint,
    @two bigint,
    @startid bigint output 
as
begin
    set @startid = @one + @two

    return @startid     
end
```

But while returning value I am getting an exception

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Can any one please help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

**Note : Above query is not the exactly the same procedure which i am using**

**UPDATED :**

I have a code like below

```
_lookupId = cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("RetVal", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                        _lookupId.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

                        _procIn01 = cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@idCount", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500);
                        cmdInsert.Parameters["@idCount"].Value = idCount;
                        _procIn01.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

                        _procIn02 = cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@requestFrom", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                        cmdInsert.Parameters["@requestFrom"].Value = clientId;
                        _procIn02.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

                        _pramOut = cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@startID", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                        _pramOut.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        cmdInsert.ExecuteScalar();
```

With out returning the value how can i assign the value to "RetVal" my _lookup variable.

Comment: Procedures return status.  Functions return values.

Comment: You don't actually have to return your output var, just setting it should be enough for the output to be populated for your app

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Procedures return a status value, which is always an integer.  You can return the value from the stored procedure just by setting it:

```
alter procedure [dbo].adding 
    -- add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @one bigint,
    @two bigint,
    @startid bigint output 
as
begin
    -- set nocount on added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with select statements.

    set @startid = @one + @two     
end;
```

Use `return` for whether or not the stored procedure succeeds.

You could call this with something like:

```
declare @startid bigint;

exec dbo.adding(1, 2, @startid output);

select @startid;
```

Comment: @Backtrack . . . Here is an example of how to write the code in C#:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905782/using-stored-procedure-output-parameters-in-c-sharp.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred because your return but you must using set to set a variable or using select

```
Set @outputvalue=@val1+@val2
```

Or

```
Select @outputvalue=@val1+@val2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sotred procedure return answer is integer number that show sp successed or not
you can not use it for getting an `big int` number
if you want get a output value with out `output parameter` then you can use select with out variable, for example,
calling

```
Select @val1+@val2
```

now for get output using `Execute Scalar` method of command.