# Calling Stored Procedure with output parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, output-parameter

This is MS Sql Server:  I have wrapped the system stored procedure, sp_sequence_get_range, so that I can have it return with a simple select (I was not able to figure out how to deal with the OUTPUT parameters in my C# framework).

This is the entire stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE GetSequenceRange( @name VARCHAR, @counter INTEGER) AS

DECLARE @firstValue SQL_VARIANT = 0;
DECLARE @lastValue SQL_VARIANT = 0;
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'EXEC sp_sequence_get_range @sequence_name = N''' + @name + N''', @range_size = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @counter)
    + N', @range_first_value = @firstValue OUTPUT, @range_last_value = @lastValue OUTPUT;'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@name VARCHAR, @counter INTEGER, @firstValue SQL_VARIANT OUTPUT, @lastValue SQL_VARIANT OUTPUT', @name, @counter, @firstValue OUTPUT, @lastValue OUTPUT
SELECT @firstValue, @lastValue
```

When I try to execute the procedure like

```sql
exec GetSequenceRange 'tablename', 3
```

I get

> Invalid object name 't'.

Whatever name I provide, the first letter is returned in this error message.

I have also tried

```sql
exec GetSequenceRange @name='tablename', @counter = 3
```

The `'tablename'` in all these examples is a qualified sequence name; I have tried both owner.sequence and database.owner.sequence.

I think there is something fundamentally wrong with my approach, but I don't see it.

Bonus for an answer that shows how to get the results from sp_sequence_get_range from a C# call without having this stored procedure wrapper in the first place.

Comment: did you try the names in square brackets? eg [mydb].[dbo].[sometable]

Comment: The missing varchar size in the create procedure statement was the problem.

Comment: You need to add the length to your variables in your dynamic sql too. You should ALWAYS ALWAYS declare the length of character variable and columns.

Comment: @SeanLange Doesn't `VARCHAR` default to `50` if not specified?

Comment: @Lankymart it is 30 in most cases. See why we should specify the length? The default is easy to forget.

Comment: @SeanLange I always do just remember reading it had a default once.

Comment: @KellyCline to avoid using a wrapper proc at all, see if this helps to call the inner stored procedure directly from C#:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905782/using-stored-procedure-output-parameters-in-c-sharp

Comment: When declaring a variable without length the default is 1, when convert/cast it will default to 30.

Comment: @TabAlleman [char and varchar (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms176089.aspx) - *"When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30."* So your both right.

Comment: @Lankymart the default varchar size in table designer is 50. Not I use the table designer ever but it is weird that it defaults to a different size.

Comment: @SeanLange Yeah good point. I haven't for years either but knew I'd seen it somewhere.

Comment: They said they would make it consistent back in 2007: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=267605 - Unfortunately, nothing has happened since then - so always specify the length yourself!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call the stored procedure directly rather easily. The following should work:

```cs
long _RangeFirstValue;
long _RangeFirstValue;

using (SqlConnection _Connection = new SqlConnection(_MyConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand _Command = _Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        _Command.CommandText = "sp_sequence_get_range";
        _Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter _ParamSequenceName =
                             new SqlParameter("sequence_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 776);
        _ParamSequenceName.Value = _MySequenceName;
        _Command.Parameters.Add(_ParamSequenceName);

        SqlParameter _ParamRangeSize = new SqlParameter("range_size", SqlDbType.BigInt);
        _ParamRangeSize.Value = _MyRangeSize;
        _Command.Parameters.Add(_ParamRangeSize);

        SqlParameter _ParamRangeFirstValue =
                             new SqlParameter("range_first_value", SqlDbType.Variant);
        _ParamRangeFirstValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        _Command.Parameters.Add(_ParamRangeFirstValue);

        SqlParameter _ParamRangeLastValue =
                             new SqlParameter("range_last_value", SqlDbType.Variant);
        _ParamRangeLastValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        _Command.Parameters.Add(_ParamRangeLastValue);

        _Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        _RangeFirstValue = (long)(_ParamRangeFirstValue.Value);
        _RangeLastValue = (long)(_ParamRangeLastValue.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Edit]

Meh. Reread the problem after posting this, and yeah, the problem is probably too-short varchars. Odds are sp_executeSQL will run fine with the "unmapped" variables. Leaving this answer here, because this code should be simplified, if only to make future maintenance and modification simpler.

---

First and foremost, I totally agree that if you can call the system procedure directly, then you should do so--dynamic SQL is a pain and is best avoided. With that said, the problem with *this* code is that your complex dynamic SQL is confused.

Step one is to build the dynanmic SQL. This is fine, I'm copying it here with some spacing for clarity:

```
SET @sql = N'EXEC sp_sequence_get_range @sequence_name = N'''
 + @name
 + N''', @range_size = '
 + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @counter)
 + N', @range_first_value = @firstValue OUTPUT, @range_last_value = @lastValue OUTPUT;'
```

Here, you are concatenating hard-coded text with passed in variables @name and @counter.  If you pass in "MyName" and "42", you get (again added spacing for clarity):

```
EXEC sp_sequence_get_range
  @sequence_name     = N'MyName'
 ,@range_size        = 42
 ,@range_first_value = @firstValue OUTPUT
 ,@range_last_value  = @lastValue OUTPUT;
```

You then pass this as the first parameter of sp_executeSQL:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql
  @sql
 ,N'@name VARCHAR, @counter INTEGER, @firstValue SQL_VARIANT OUTPUT, @lastValue SQL_VARIANT OUTPUT'
 ,@name
 ,@counter
 ,@firstValue OUTPUT
 ,@lastValue OUTPUT
```

And there it is--you're attempting to pass in @name and @counter as parameters to sp_executeSQL, which you do not need to do because they are hard-coded into the dynamic SQL text. Moreover, they are not defined as parameters within @sql for sp_executeSQL to pass (map?) it's parameter-defined values into. Take them out, and it should be fine:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql
  @sql
 ,N'@firstValue SQL_VARIANT OUTPUT, @lastValue SQL_VARIANT OUTPUT'
 ,@firstValue OUTPUT
 ,@lastValue OUTPUT
```