# c# how to get printout info from sql server query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

```
DECLARE @message VARCHAR(10)
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'{0}')
BEGIN
    SET @message = '{1}'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @message = 'NOT_OK'
END

PRINT(@message)
```

I execute above command from c# app.

How can I get print message?
Im trying like this:

```
        if(connection.State.ToString() == "Closed")
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
        SqlCommand newCmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        newCmd.Connection = connection;
        newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        newCmd.CommandText = string.Format(queriesMgr.getQuery(SqlQueriesID.IS_TABLE_EXISTS), "student", "OK");

        SqlDataReader reader = newCmd.ExecuteReader();


        if (reader.Read())
        {
            //not enter here(no data to read)
        }
```

Anyone could tell me what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Make @message an output parameter E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905782/using-stored-procedure-output-parameters-in-c-sharp

Comment: ('{0}' looks like an interpolation placeholder, there is none of that in T-SQL)

Comment: @AlexK. -- as he says that is his C# code.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the following query your reader will see the output select.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'{0}')
BEGIN
    SELECT '{1}'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 'NOT_OK'
END
```