# Getting an error calling my stored procedure from c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which works in SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_fetch_journal_search]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @sJournalText nvarchar(250) OUT,
    @dJournalDate date OUT,
    @sJournalTime nvarchar(250) OUT,
    @sJournalImageName nvarchar(250) OUT,
    @sJournalWebsite nvarchar (250) OUT,
    @iJournalID int OUT,
    @iJournalEntryID int OUT,
    @sSearch nvarchar(250)
AS
BEGIN           
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select  @dJournalDate = journal_date, 
            @sJournalTime = journal_time, 
            @sJournalImageName = journal_text, 
            @sJournalImageName= image_name, 
            @sJournalWebsite = website,
            @sJournalText = journal_text,
            @iJournalEntryID = journal_entry_id,
            @iJournalID = journal_id 
    from journalview
    where journal_date like '%' + @sSearch + '%'
    or journal_time like '%' + @sSearch + '%'
    or journal_text like '%' + @sSearch + '%'
    or image_name like '%' + @sSearch + '%'
    or website like '%' + @sSearch + '%'
    group by journal_date, journal_time, journal_text, image_name, website, journal_id,journal_entry_id
```

When I call it from c# I get an error on the ExecuteReader command which says int is incompatible with date.  I can't see what is wrong:

```
SqlCommand cmdFetchJournal = new SqlCommand();
cmdFetchJournal.Connection = ConnectData.connection;
cmdFetchJournal.CommandText = "sp_fetch_journal_search";
cmdFetchJournal.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmdFetchJournal.Parameters.AddWithValue("sSearch", (sSearch != null ? sSearch : ""));
cmdFetchJournal.Parameters["sSearch"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmdFetchJournal.Parameters.AddWithValue("sJournalText", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmdFetchJournal.Parameters["sJournalText"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmdFetchJournal.Parameters.AddWithValue("dJournalDate", SqlDbType.Date);
cmdFetchJournal.Parameters["dJournalDate"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmdFetchJournal.Parameters.AddWithValue("sJournalTime", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmdFetchJournal.Parameters["sJournalTime"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmdFetchJournal.Parameters.AddWithValue("sJournalWebsite", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmdFetchJournal.Parameters["sJournalWebsite"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmdFetchJournal.Parameters.AddWithValue("sJournalImageName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmdFetchJournal.Parameters["sJournalImageName"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmdFetchJournal.Parameters.AddWithValue("iJournalID", SqlDbType.Int);
cmdFetchJournal.Parameters["iJournalID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
cmdFetchJournal.Parameters.AddWithValue("iJournalEntryID", SqlDbType.Int);
cmdFetchJournal.Parameters["iJournalEntryID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
SqlDataReader drFetchJournal = cmdFetchJournal.ExecuteReader();
```

All help much appreciated.

Comment: yes i tried it as a date type but got the same error

Comment: The field underneath is a Date type too.  The line where I get the error is the ExecuteReader command above.

Comment: Why out parameters as opposed to returning a result set?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: SQL has various `Date` types, are you trying to squash a `DateTime` into a `Date`?

Comment: Something worth a read as well... http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ though you are calling a SP so not really relevant--but good to know for future use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed that these are `output`, so you need to use the `Add` method instead of `AddWithValue`. I'm going to leave the remainder of this answer as reference.

The reason that you are having this issue is that you are not supplying the value for your `Parameters.AddWithValue()` call. So when you call

```
Parameters.AddWithValue("dJournalDate", SqlDbType.VarChar);
```

You are setting the value to `SqlDbType.VarChar` which is probably `1`. If you change it to be

```
Parameters.AddWithValue("dJournalDate", yourDate);
```

You should be fine. This goes for all your other `Parameters.AddWithValue()` calls also.

Comment: Your welcome. You are also going to have problems getting the data with the way you currently have it. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905782/using-stored-procedure-output-parameters-in-c-sharp) question for the way to execute stored procedures `ExecuteNonQuery` and access output parameter values.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
cmdFetchJournal.Parameters.AddWithValue("dJournalDate", SqlDbType.VarChar);
```

`dJournalDate` is a date, but you are trying to pass in a VarChar. Change it to this:

```
cmdFetchJournal.Parameters.AddWithValue("dJournalDate", SqlDbType.Date);
```