# SQL Server stored procedure output parameter and return data from select

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, output, entity-framework-core

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetImmediateManager   
   @managerID INT OUTPUT  
AS  
BEGIN  
   SET @managerID = 6;

   SELECT * 
   FROM Roles;
END
```

When I remove `select * from Roles;` the output value (`@managerID`) is returned correctly to my C# code. But when the procedure has `select * ..`, the value returned by output parameter is null.

How can I return select and output at the same time?

In C# my code looks like this:

```
dbContext.Database.OpenConnection();

DbCommand cmd = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandTimeout = 15;
cmd.CommandText = "GetImmediateManager";
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

var rowsCountParam = new SqlParameter("@managerID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
rowsCountParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(rowsCountParam);

using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    tasks = reader.MapToList<TaskManagerTask>();
    //rowsCount = (int)rowsCountParam.Value;
}
```

Comment: Why dont you return `@managerID` with table like `SELECT *, @managerID managerID FROM Roles;`

Comment: [When you use a DataReader object, you must close it or read to the end of the data before you can view the output parameters](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/308621/output-parameters-are-not-returned-when-you-run-an-ado-net-command-in?wa=wsignin1.0)

Comment: This isn't EF Core, it's plain ADO.NET. Output parameters are returned *after* the reader finishes. What does `MapToList` do? Does it read to the end?

Comment: @uzi why do you assume there's a problem with output parameters? How would you read *two* result sets?

Comment: Is this a duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10905782/125981

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplistic answer is to add `@managerID` to your select statement

For a less simplistic perhaps the following, I changed the names a bit to reflect the use, get parameter after it closes.

```
var managerIDParam = new SqlParameter("@managerID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
managerIDParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(managerIDParam);

using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    tasks = reader.MapToList<TaskManagerTask>();
}
int managerIDParamUsed = (int)managerIDParam.Value;
```

Comment: Output parameters aren't broken