# SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery returns -1

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have stored proc that returns various integers based on few conditions. It does not has any Select statement. when I use

```
SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery("ConString",CommandType.StoredProcedure,"ProcName")
```

this ExecuteNonQuery returns -1. What does -1 mean here?

Comment: Where is SqlHelper coming from? Is it your own class, because I can find no reference to it anywhere. Perhaps taking a look at that code might help you out.

Comment: You should use the out parameters of the stored-procedure. Just google it and you find: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905782/using-stored-procedure-output-parameters-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Silvermind it is a wrapper of Sqlcommand, a library I downloaded from Github..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `SqlHelper` is a wrapper for `SqlCommand`...

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.7.2) states:

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

So, depending on your query / proc, it either:

- is not an `UPDATE`, `INSERT` or `DELETE` statement or can't affect any rows
- has caused a rollback to occur