# How to use the output parameter insert stored procedure in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have stored procedure as follows

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp1]
    @mat NVARCHAR(1000) = NULL,
    @party NVARCHAR(1000) = NULL,
    @place NVARCHAR(1000) = NULL,
    @truk NVARCHAR(1000) = NULL,
    @qty NUMERIC(10) = NULL,
    @ptm NUMERIC(10) = NULL,
    @mop NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @tos NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @driver NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @date1 DATE = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000); 
    DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(4000); 
    DECLARE @rate NUMERIC(10); 

    SET @sql ='select  @rate = ['+@mat+']   from tblcos'+ ' where [Name] = @party' 
    set @params = '@party nvarchar (1000), @rate NVARCHAR(10) OUTPUT'  
    exec sp_executesql @sql, @params,@party= @party,@rate = @rate OUTPUT

    INSERT INTO tblsls([Party], [Place], [truk], [Material], [Qty], rate, [Amount], [Payment], [Balance], [MOP], [TOS], [driver], [Date]) 
        SELECT 
            @party, @place, @truk, @mat, @rate, @qty, (@qty * @rate),
            @ptm, (@qty * @rate - @ptm), @mop, @tos, @driver, @date1
END
```

My `aspx.cs` file

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection (@"
     Data Source = ABC - PC; Initial Catalog = VRA; Integrated Security = True");

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp1", con);
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Date", Calendar1.SelectedDate);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("party", Ddprt.SelectedValue);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Place", tbpls.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Truk", Tbtru.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Material", Ddmat.SelectedValue);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Qty", Tbqty.Text);
     **cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Rate",         );**
     **cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Amount",          );**
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Payment", Tbptm.Text);
     **cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Balance",            );**
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MOP", Ddmop.SelectedValue);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TOS", Ddtos.SelectedValue);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("driver", Tbdri.Text);

     con.Open();

     int k = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     if (k != 0)
     {
         Lbmsg.Text = "Record inserted successfully into the database";
         Lbmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.CornflowerBlue;
     }

     con.Close();
}
```

How to make `Rate`, `Amount` and `Balance` to take the value from the stored procedure `sp1` and update the value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using stored procedure output parameters in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905782/using-stored-procedure-output-parameters-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is value when you say "...and update the value"? Any why are you using  `sp_executesql` when you could just `SELECT` the values directly?

Comment: yes i am using  sp_executesql , let me know how to take the value directly

Comment: in store procedure i am supplying values for 10 parameter and procedure will update values for 13 columns , i want to do the same in asp.net web app also

Comment: @VinayAparanji Then call the procedure from the web app..? Like you are doing..?

Comment: but what should i feed   *cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Rate",         );**
                                       **cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Amount",          );**

Comment: **cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Balance",            );**   can you kindly let me know

Answer (score 1):

Create another procedure that accepts `Rate`, `Amount`, and `Balance` as parameters and call that one instead from your web app. That way you don't ruin the functionality of the existing `sp1`, but still have what you need.

I don't know much about syntax in sql, but I think it looks something like this. Somebody please correct if wrong.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp1_fromWeb]
    @mat NVARCHAR(1000) = NULL,
    @party NVARCHAR(1000) = NULL,
    @place nvarchar(1000)=null,
    @truk nvarchar (1000)=null,
    @qty numeric (10)=null,
    @ptm numeric(10)=null,
    @mop nvarchar(100)=null,
    @tos nvarchar(100)=null,
    @driver nvarchar(100)=null,
    @date1 date = null,
    @rate numeric(10),
    @amount numeric(10),
    @balance numeric(10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000); 
    DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(4000); 

    SET @sql ='select  @rate = ['+@mat+']   from tblcos'+ ' where [Name] = @party' 
    set @params = '@party nvarchar (1000), @rate NVARCHAR(10) OUTPUT'  
    exec sp_executesql @sql, @params,@party= @party,@rate = @rate OUTPUT

    INSERT INTO tblsls([Party],[Place],[truk], [Material],[Qty], rate,[Amount],[Payment],[Balance],[MOP],[TOS],[driver],[Date]) 
        SELECT @party, @place, @truk, @mat, @qty, @rate, @amount, @ptm, @balance, @mop, @tos, @driver, @date1
END
```

Comment: its wont work, i am want to know the the cmd.paramerters .addwithvalues part