# Loading Microsoft Reports the proper way

Tags: c#, wpf, reportviewer, reportbuilder3.0

I'm using Wpf to View Some reports using Report Viewer .. I designed the a report using sql report builder 'ReportByTopic.rdl' added it to the solution  .. the DataSet inside the rdl file named 'Dataset1' and there are three parameters @TopicId ,@SDate, @EDate
tested the query and it's working fine

I am trying to load filterd data into ReportViewer but no data is viewed

and here's the code

```
private void reportViewer_load()
{
    ReportParameter[] Params = new ReportParameters[3];
    Params[0] = new ReportParameter("TopicId", "4");
    Params[1] = new ReportParameter("SDate", "2009-01-01");
    Params[2] = new ReportParameter("EDate", "2017-01-01");

    ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
    rds.Name = "DataSet1";

    reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports\ReportByTopic.rdl";
  reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSource.Add(rds)
    reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(Params);
    reportViewer.Refresh();
}
```

so where did I go wrong

**UPDATE**

Based on the answers I made some changes to the above code. First I used a method 'GetData' which returns a datatable of all the data I need using the same query I used to design the rdl file . 
The edited code

```
    private void reportViewer_load()
{
    ReportParameter[] Params = new ReportParameters[3];
    Params[0] = new ReportParameter("TopicId", "4");
    Params[1] = new ReportParameter("SDate", "2009-01-01");
    Params[2] = new ReportParameter("EDate", "2017-01-01");

    ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", GetData());


    reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports\ReportByTopic.rdl";
  reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSource.Add(rds)
    reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(Params);
    reportViewer.Refresh();
}
```

the datatable gets filled correctly with 900 rows, but still the reportViewer doesn't

Comment: See the update of the answer based in your updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You omitted to pass the data to the report, when creating the ReportDataSource pass the DataSet name and the data to its constructor:

```
IEnumerable data = GetFromDataBase(...);
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1",data);

reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports\ReportByTopic.rdl";
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSource.Add(rds)
```

Take a look to [ReportDataSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportdatasource.aspx) constructors for more details.

> UPDATE:

From your update I spot a problem. You are invoking the ***Refresh*** method of the control base class, when you actually want to invoke ***RefreshReport***. They are used for two different things. So your last four lines need to be replaced by this:

```
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports\ReportByTopic.rdl";
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear() //Added line
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSource.Add(rds)
reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(Params);
reportViewer.RefreshReport(); //Replaced line
```

Note that I first invoke ***Clear*** method before setting the datasource. This is useful when you want to reload/refresh report without closing it.

Comment: I specified the query in the rdl file's dataset .. doesn't it gets the data automatically using that query?

Comment: You only specified the schema for the report, but the actual data needs to be explicitly provided.

Comment: ok thank you for the answer .. but I would appreciate a little more help .. If the data is retrieved from various tables with many types and unable to be in a collection .. what is the proper object I put these data in

Comment: because I retrieved the data in a data table and it's still not working

Comment: The easiest way is to create a stored procedure to output the desire data. Then in code invoke the stored procedure and store the result in a datatable or another collection of your choice. Havee a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933855/how-can-i-retrieve-a-table-from-stored-procedure-to-a-datatable and http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/dal-retrieve-a-datatable-using-a-stored-procedure/

Comment: I've done that .. the data is loaded successfully into the datatable .. but still no records in the reportViewer.

Comment: Edit the question and post the new code you are using.