# About MySQL stored procedure with one parameter with C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to check if an Id number exist in MySQL DB with stored procedure.
This is my procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`mm`@`%` PROCEDURE `tts`(
IN `Id` INT)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM login WHERE Id = Id;
END
```

This is my code for callin procedure:

```
private void btnEx_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try {
        conn = new MySqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = cs;
        MySqlParameter pm = new MySqlParameter("Id", MySqlDbType.Int32);
        pm.Value = Int32.Parse(tbId.Text);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "tts";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(pm);
        conn.Open();
        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1) {
            MessageBox.Show("OK!");
        } else {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed!");
        }
    }
    catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

When the button is pressed i get "Failed!". Where I am wrong?

Comment: What is `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` returning?

Comment: @mjwills It returns 0

Comment: When you execute the stored procedure in MySQL it returns a record, right?

Comment: @Albert Yes, it returns 1 row

Comment: I think you might want to look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933855/how-can-i-retrieve-a-table-from-stored-procedure-to-a-datatable Because you are using a stored procedure that returns a table (not update, delete or insert), which makes the ExecuteNonQuery always return -1.

Comment: i would drop that stored procedure, this stored procedure is *"overkill"* for what you are trying to do here and not justifiable to use here in my opinion

Comment: Even if it _is_ an overkill, stored procedures are not to blame here. :)

Comment: .. also be aware that using  MySQL directly in C# requires you to totally open up the MySQL on the internet.. Also you are exposing your MySQL username and password aswell in the application you ideally should be using a gateway like serversocket-clientsocket implementation or a webservice (REST, SOAP, XML-RPC, GraphQL) to connect to the database so the MySQL username and password is on the server only..

Comment: 'SELECT * FROM login WHERE Id = Id;'  I cannot tell which iid s the parameter and which is the column - mysql treats them both as the column. You should rename the parameter.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I fully agree with your statement about MySQL credentials being exposed in the client application, and about how the infrastructure should be (e.g. WebServices). Also, we _are_ moving offtopic :)

Comment: to add to @P.Salmon comment `'SELECT * FROM login WHERE login.Id = Id;'` should also work fine in some MySQL versions..

Comment: *"and about how the infrastructure should be (e.g. WebServices)"* you mean security wise ? @EricWu well because i most off the time use a Chromium-based control in mine C# apps anyway to get rich and easy GUI with html5 , css and javascript .. I think i would try to implement [w3c web auth standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/)   which can auth on based on usb hardware tokens or windows hello assuming those browser controls already have support for it (not jet tested)  .. Also explained here https://webauthn.guide/

Comment: @RaymondNijland WebServices were just an example of how to implement a better infrastructure (yes, security-wise). Will be sure to check out the W3C rules on these auth modes. Thanks :)

Comment: but be sure to still to use `https` otherwise as that web auth is still unsecure for the *"man (or woman for that matter we all mostly likely saw the movie the matrix :-)) in the middle attacks"* without using `https` @EricWu

Comment: Problem is solved using MySqlDataReader insted of ExecuteNonQuery()

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your procedure returns a `DataTable`. Executing `NonQuery` means that the connector will attempt to find a `scalar` value (`int, bool`), from which `DataTable` can't be converted to.

Change your procedure to return a column (such as the `Id` itself):

`SELECT Id  FROM login WHERE Id = Id`

Then, change your code to check if the `Id` received is `DBNull.Value`, which will indicate if the value has been received.

```
if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() != DBNull.Value)
{
    MessageBox.Show("OK!");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Failed!");
}
```

Comment: Yes, using MySqlDataReader works fine, btw changing selection only to Id does not work, if I use ExecuteNonQuery always returns me 0.